# Excel formula sum if string contains value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to ask if it is possible to calculate cells B9 and B10 automatically in the following picture?
[image]

Comment: Please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You formula should look something like: B9: =sumif($A$2:$A$6;"`*apple*`";$B$2:$B$6). $ - is to lock the cell, `*apple*` - means that the cell contain string "apple"

Comment: if you want to get automatically  *apple*, *pare* you could put in cell "C9" that formula ="*"&LEFT(A9,LEN(A9)-1)&"*" and change the formula in B9 to =sumif($A$2:$A$6;C9;$B$2:$B$6), and just and copy/paste B9 and C9 to B10 and C10 and so on